# Filter checkout session by metadata Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments, nestjs

I'm building a marketplace (you can imagine it like an Ebay where there are buyer and seller). And i want to get an items that bought customer (and vice versa with seller).

Here is my checkout session service:

```
async charge(userId: number, dto: CreateChargeDto) {
        //Get an item by id
        const item = await this.prisma.item.findUnique({
          where: {
            id: dto.itemId,
          },
        });

    if (!item) {
      throw new BadRequestException('There is no item with this id');
    }
    // Search for user
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
    });
    //update customer
    await this.updateCustomer(user.stripeCustomerId, dto);

    const session = await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
      success_url: 'http://localhost:3000/success?message=Succesful+payment',
      cancel_url: 'http://localhost:3000/404?message=Payment+canceled',
      mode: 'payment',
      currency: 'pln',
      customer: user.stripeCustomerId,
      customer_update: {
        address: 'auto',
      },
      metadata: {
        seller_id: item.userId, // here is where i save seller id
      },
      line_items: [
        {
          quantity: 1,
          price_data: {
            currency: 'pln',
            unit_amount: item.price * 100,
            product_data: {
              name: item.name,
              images: item.images,
              metadata: {
                id: item.id, 
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ],
    });

    return session.id;
  }

  async getCheckoutList(userId: number) {
    const user = await this.prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: {
        id: userId,
      },
    });

    const checkouts = await this.stripe.

    

    return checkouts.data;
  }
```

And now i wanna filter this session checkouts so i can display them in buyer (or seller) personal page.

```
const checkouts = await this.stripe.checkout.sessions.list({
      where: {
        metadata: {
          seller_id: // seller id
        }
      }
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the best in my opinion in this situation is to use a webhook.

The perfect example in Nestjs you can read here: https://wanago.io/2021/07/05/api-nestjs-stripe-events-webhooks/

Answer (score 2):

There's currently no way to filter for Checkout Sessions by metadata.

Some other options are :

- Listen for the `checkout.session.completed` webhook event, save the data to your DB and then perform your own filtering. See https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks for more information on handling webhooks.
- Add the metadata to the PaymentIntent also using the following parameter : https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-payment_intent_data-metadata. You can then use the Search API to filter for the
  corresponding PaymentIntent with https://stripe.com/docs/search. Once
  you have the PaymentIntent, retrieve the corresponding
  Checkout Session with
  https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-payment_intent

To filter for Checkout Sessions by Customer, you can use https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/list#list_checkout_sessions-customer